# iPhone keeps restarting itself every 3 minutes

Tags: iphone, startup, restore

I just got an iPhone 5 from my friend. It worked well and I decided to restore it to reset it. Yet it is now restarting itself every 3 minutes so I'm trying to do a factory restore. While letting it connected to my computer I pushed the top and menu button and went to iTunes. I get this message ~without any interaction~:

> iTunes is downloading the software for this phone and will restore

[image]

~It seems to be stuck, but it eventually restarted but~ it keeps restarting itself every 3 minutes.

Between restarts I can start to set the IPhone or even to use it a bit as everybody does if I was fast enough to set it.

#### Update

I think I achieved to reinstall the OS, but it keeps restarting itself every 3 minutes.

Comment: How long has this been happening?

Comment: Can you [edit](https://apple.stackexchange.com/posts/347717/edit) the question and specify what do you see on the screen between restarts?

Comment: @DaniilManokhin the restarting trouble ? Since I restored it. the _"itunes is downloading the software for this phone and will restore"_ message ? 5 to 10 minutes and the it seemed the IPhone autonomously decided to restart. I don't exclude the possibility that it has some troubles with the usb port, as I tried two wires since this morning (one official, one unofficial)

Comment: @ThePassenger have you seen https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201263

Comment: @DaniilManokhin Yes, I based my actions on it

Comment: You’re in something called a “boot loop”.   I would try hard resetting the phone then restore from backup.

Comment: @Allan, Yes, it seems. Yet, I'm not sure I have any backup as far as I just get it from my best friend who lives in another country

Comment: Without a backup, you pretty much have one choice: hard reset and recreate your data; you can’t use your device as it is.

Answer (score 1):

Since using iTunes to restore the iPhone can't solve this problem, the following method is worth a try:

1. Restore all settings on your iPhone.
2. Update all applications or remove potentially conflicting applications
3. Remove the SIM card from the iPhone and check if it stops restarting
4. Check and clean the charging port
5. If you restart when charging, please replace the iPhone battery
   Finally, it is recommended to contact Apple officials for the best solution.

https://www.fonecope.com/fix-iphone-keeps-restarting.html